# Oracle - copying stored procedures to remote database

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

An assignment I have as part of my pl/sql studies requires me to create a remote database connection and copy down all my tables to it from local, and then also copy my other objects that reference data, so my views and triggers etc.

The idea is that at the remote end, the views etc should reference the local tables provided the local database is online, and if it is not, then they should reference the tables stored on the remote database.

So I've created a connection, and a script that creates the tables at the remote end.

I've also made a pl/sql block to create all the views and triggers at the remote end, whereby a simple select query is run against the local database to check if it is online, if it is online then a series of execute immediate statements creates the views etc with reference to table_name@local, and if it isn't online the block skips to the exception section, where a similar series of execute immediate statements creates the same views but referencing the remote tables.

OK so this is where I become unsure.
I have a package that contains a few procedures and a function, and I'm not sure what's the best way to create that at the remote end so that it behaves in a similar way in terms of where it picks up its reference tables from.

Is it simply a case of enclosing the whole package-creating block within an 'execute immediate', in the same way as I did for the views, or should I create two different packages and call them something like pack1 and pack1_remote?

Or is there as I suspect a more efficient method of achieving the goal?

cheers!

Comment: Let's call your local database A and the remote database B. You want to create objects in B. You appear to be saying that you want the objects in B to reference the tables in A if A is online and otherwise to use the objects in B.  Is that accurate?  If so, are you trying to make that determination at compile time?  Or at runtime?  It makes little sense to make this determination at compile time since that's a single point in time and you can just ensure that A is up at that time. Making the choice at runtime would be potentially useful but would preclude the use of views (among other things).

Comment: If you're trying to make the determination at runtime, you're designing the system incorrectly.  You'd want to build replication between the databases so that the data is kept in sync and the code can always refer to local objects.  That's a radically more stable, more performant, and more maintainable solution.

Comment: I'm not sure Justin to tell you the truth.  Maybe the idea is that the script that does the testing of online/offline should be run at the start of the user session..I don't have much detail on it.  Notwithstanding the fact that this might not be the most stabe approach would you have any thoughts on the stored procedures/package?

Comment: Do you want to make the determination once at compile time?  Or at runtime?  The two approaches would be completely and totally different.  Re-installing all the application objects when a user logs in would, I suppose, be possible but it would be insane on so many different levels.  If you're just learning PL/SQL, none of this strikes me as a reasonable interpretation of an assignment.

Comment: My best guess would be once at compile time..

Comment: your understanding of the task as per your first comment is right by the way Justin!

Answer (score 1):

This is absolutely not how any reasonable person in the real world would design a system.  Suggesting something like what I suggest here in the real world will, in the best case, get you laughed out of the room.

The least insane approach I could envision would be to have two different schemas.  Schema 1 would own the tables.  Schema 2 would own the code.  At install time, create synonyms for every object that schema 2 needs to reference.  If the remote database is available when the code is installed, create synonyms that refer to objects in the remote database.  Otherwise, create synonyms that refer to objects in the local database.  That lets you create a single set of objects without using dynamic SQL by creating an extra layer of indirection between your code and your tables.